# How to add multiple color schemes in one stylesheet In HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to add multiple color schemes in one stylesheet which works onclick  like wordpress, magento etc.. where themes are available on their stores with different colors.

Comment: How'd you change from one color scheme to another?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this with 1 stylesheet?  It would be easier to separate each theme into its own CSS file and then switch out which file is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the color schemes by toggling a class on the `body` element. Make multiple versions in your CSS referencing this class for all elements that change with the color schemes.

```
body.colorscheme-dark {
    /* Changes that are inheritable */
    color: #fff;
}

body.colorscheme-dark #content #comment-section {
    /* Specific changes to this element */
    border-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

You can create unlimited schemes like this.

Now change them with a simple function like this:

```
function swapTheme(theme) {
    $(body).removeClass().addClass(theme);
}
```

jQuery for clarity, just comment if you'd like that in vanilla js.